# How to validate branch name before pushing in Git?

Tags: git

How could I make sure that the only branches that are pushed to `origin` are:

- `master`
- `bug/*`
- `feature/*`

?

The behavior should be:

- If branch name is allowed (one of the above), the branch is pushed to `origin`.
- Otherwise, error message is displayed: "You are not allowed to push this branch"

What would be the easiest way to force this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing a git hook

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html

If you're aiming for client side, `update` hook looks like what you might want.

Otherwise you can implement it on the server side with `pre-receive`

What you need to do is write a script that will take check to make sure the branch is whitelisted before allowing the push.  Returning a 0 exit status indicates ok, anything nonzero will prevent the operation

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19298300/240443) shows what to do with `pre-receive` to do this in considerable detail. Check out the [linked script](http://web.torek.net/torek/git/pre-receive.sh.txt) for detailed ideas.